# Compact a VHD file created by Disk Management?

Tags: windows, vhd

My computer is running on Windows 7 64-bit. I used Disk Management to create a new VHD file and made it into a new virtual drive. The size of the disk is 8GB. After using about 3GB, I decided to format it. However after formatting the size of the disk is still 3GB.

I tried diskpart to compact this VHD file and I got this error message

> Virtual Disk Service error: The requested operation requires that the
>   virtual disk be attached read only.

So, is there any way to compact this VHD file?

Comment: Try unmounting the disk before compacting it...

Comment: Where is that option to unmount the disk?

Comment: Inside Disk Management, right-click the Disk (not the volume) and there should be an Unmount or Eject option in the menu

Comment: I don't see that option, only "Detach VHD", here is the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/OyH1C.png

Comment: That's the one, Detach VHD, then follow the instructions here: http://linhost.info/2011/01/windows-how-to-compact-a-dynamic-vhd/

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much for your help but I can't mark your comment as answer. Also is there another faster way not to use diskpart or some kind of automation tool for this?

Comment: Happy to help :) I'll post it as an answer in a second, there may be some 3rd party tools out there to automate it but I just tend to use diskpart personally (or Hyper-V Manager on Windows 8/Server)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compacting can't be completed on a VHD that is attached unless it is read-only.

To detach the disk, you need to right-click the VHD disk in Disk Management and select Detach VHD:

[image: Detach VHD]

You can then complete the compacting using `diskpart` from a Command Prompt:

1. Run `diskpart`
2. Select the disk via its path: `select vdisk file="<path>"`
3. Attach it as read-only: `attach vdisk readonly`
4. Compact it: `compact vdisk`
5. Upon completion of the compact, detach it again: `detach vdisk`

You can then re-attach it via Disk Management in its normal and newly compacted state.

(Reference: http://linhost.info/2011/01/windows-how-to-compact-a-dynamic-vhd/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to compact vhd (under windows):

1. **Important!** Mount vhd in Disk Management and defrag. This step allows shrink volume to get maximum free space
2. **Important!** Shrink vhd partition in Disk Management.
3. **Important!** Create new FAT32 partition on free space and formating it (not qickly). This step clears the disk data, without it there will be no reduction of vhd file size.
4. Delete FAT32 partition.
5. Extend vhd partition to full size.
6. Run cmd as Administrator and :

   diskpart

   select vdisk file="my.vhd"

   compact vdisk

Without steps 1-3, the vhd file size will not decrease