# Not enough disk space to merge/compact/shrink Hyper-V disk

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, disk-space

I have a Hyper-V VM on my local machine. The VM disk has expanded so that I no longer have any disk space on my local machine. Due to the lack of disk space the latest merge is failing. This means that I cannot *edit* the VM drive to compact it *because checkpoints exist for this drive*. How can I regain disk space on my local machine? The only thing I can think of is to copy the VM to an external drive, work on it there and then copy it back.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly (to me at least) I was able to use [{{DISKPART}} to compact](https://superuser.com/a/495327/45975) the disk image without completing the merge.

1. Run `diskpart`
2. Select the disk via its path: `select vdisk file="<path>"`
3. Attach it as read-only: `attach vdisk readonly`
4. Compact it: `compact vdisk`
5. Upon completion of the compact, detach it again: `detach vdisk`